# How do I get rid of escape sequences when using SSHTools?

Tags: java, ssh, terminal, j2ssh

I am using [SSHTools](http://sshtools.sourceforge.net/) / J2SSH to connect to a server via SSH. Everything works fine, only problem is, that the output contains strange escape sequences / characters. I read somewhere, that these are color codes and that it is not an encoding issue.
Now my question is: How do I get rid of them? Seems like I need some sort of Terminal Emulation, which interprets or strips off these codes.
Here is the output of `ls`:

```
[0m[01;34msketchbook[0m  sketchbook.tar  sketchbook.tar.tar  [01;32msshsudo[0m  [01;34mtmp[0m  tmp.tar
```

(Note: There are other commands I need to call, so `ls --color=never` won’t do the job.)

I tried the library [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) before, there you can use `((ChannelShell)channel).setPty(false);` to get rid of these characters, but I did not find something similar for SSHTools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just found out myself.
Download [Terminal Components](http://www.sshtools.com/products/terminal-components) library.

Then the following will work (based on [this](http://www.sshtools.com/archives/448) blogpost):

```
      IOStreamConnector input = new IOStreamConnector();
      IOStreamConnector error = new IOStreamConnector();
      input.setCloseInput(false);
      error.setCloseOutput(false);
      input.connect(System.in, session.getOutputStream());
      error.connect(session.getStderrInputStream(), System.out);

      InputStream in = session.getInputStream();
      TerminalEmulation emulation = new TerminalEmulation("vt320");
      emulation.setRecordPrintableOnly(true);
      emulation.startRecording(System.out);
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      int r;
      while ((r = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
          emulation.putBytes(buf, 0, r);
      }
```